# Is it possible to encrypt data in Azure and retrieve it on a website?

Tags: azure, encryption

I would like you please to guide me, and let me know if it's possible to encrypt data in the hard-drives (Azure), they are sensitive videos and images, I am retrieving them via a website, but I want them to be encrypted in the hard drive as second challenge if there is any attack on my server.

Is it possible to do it and in the same time the encrypted data will be indexed in the website and watchable?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with encryption is who hold the keys. With asymmetric encryption it is certainly possible to store encrypted files (either in blob storage or elsewhere) and then decrypt them.

However, if your website can decrypt them then they hold the keys. So if your website is compromised and exposes that key then anyone can read them.

The question becomes what kind of attack/server intrusion are you really trying to avoid.

One approach might be 2 servers. 1 with your website and 1 with storage and then set up a connection between those servers in such a way that your storage is only accessible from your first server.

Comment: Thanks for your kind respond, the attacks from both the server side, and the website itself

Comment: But what kind of attacks? injection attacks? if you let your website decrypt and someone can decrypt one file you might trick your site in letting them decrypt other files as well. Brute force password attacks? encryption won't help you there. Accidentally make a file world readable? then encryption might help.

Comment: Yes Injection, Xss and LFI attacks.  I am also worried about the software that i installed from the dev company that it might have a buffer overflow or something like that that might lead to a direct attack in the server and expose all the files there, that's why i wanted to encrypt the data as a second security option.